# What does emitting an input event do if nothing seems to explicitly use an input event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

We have a Vuetify 3 component called `FilterPanel`; a simplified version follows:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-select v-model="field" :items="fields" :menu-props="{ auto: true }">
            <v-field />
          </v-select>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-text-field v-model="text" :type="(formats && formats[field]) || 'text'" @keyup.enter="add" />
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2">
          <v-btn @click="add()">
            Add Filter
            <v-icon end theme="dark"> mdi-filter-plus </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
    <v-chip>
      ... removed for brevity
    </v-chip>
  </div>
</template>
```

The Vuetify 2 version of this was similar:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field v-model="text" :type="(formats && formats[field]) || 'text'" @keyup.enter="add">
      <v-select slot="prepend-inner" v-model="field" :items="fields" menu-props="auto" />
      <v-btn slot="append" @click="add()" >
        Add Filter
        <v-icon right dark>mdi-filter-plus</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-text-field>
    <v-chip>
      ... removed for brevity
    </v-chip>
  </div>
</template>
```

Later on in the file (in the `<scripts>`), there are these lines in various `methods` on the exported object:

`this.$emit('input', { ...this.value, ...qFields })`

`this.$emit('input', { ...this.value, [this.field]: this.text })`

`this.$emit('input', omit(this.value, key))`

In the Vuetify 2 version, `this.value` basically seemed to be equivalent to `{ [this.field]: this.text }` (except w/ getters and setters). I'm not sure if it's because of the reorganized code or because of a Vuetify change, but `this.value` now seems to be undefined.

What exactly are these emits supposed to accomplish? I don't see any `@input` anywhere in our codebase, and I looked at various components in the tree from Vuetify, and none explicitly mention an `input` event, either.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to figure out is whether I should:

1. just delete the emits
2. do something funky to reconstruct `this.value` (e.g.
   `this.$emit('input', { ...{ [this.field]: this.text }, ...qFields })`)
3. change these based on some change in Vuetify 3 that weren't in
   the migration guide? I did notice this: `@input event has been replaced by @update:model-value on components that support v-model usage.` but I'm not sure exactly what needs to be done if that's relevant - change the first emit parameter, but then what about the second parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm *guessing* this might trigger the data table on the outer layer to fetch/update data.

Comment: You say it's "fairly clear," but the language I quoted certainly seems ambiguous enough that we are interpreting it differently. It's rather hard to find stackoverflow posts in browser history unless you can use keywords in your title, and the policy has a "if you want to" clause. The current title now sucks because it will just blend in with any other random stackoverflow post. It's NBD one-time, but either StackOverflow should change that page to be more clear what they mean by "regular English" or drop it. (Edit: and your comments all disappeared. Weird. Whatever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not seeing any `@input` events because the component is used with `v-model`.

In Vue 2, `v-model` is shorthand for binding to a prop `:value` and listening to an event `@input`. In Vue 3, that has been changed to setting the prop `:modelValue` and listening to the event `@update:modelValue`. I think this is what you need to change - rename `value` to `modelValue` and instead of emitting an `input` event, emit `update:modelValue`.

---

To add some details, it looks like this is a custom component that allows to select from a number of properties and then set the corresponding value in the `this.value` object. I think it also allows to override several properties to a preset value and probably to remove a property altogether.

This is the emit when the user inputs data for a selected field:

```
this.$emit('input', { ...this.value, [this.field]: this.text })
```

It creates a new object containing everything from the input prop `:value` except that the prop given in `this.field` is changed to the value in `this.text`.

This is the emit when several properties are overridden:

```
this.$emit('input', { ...this.value, ...qFields })
```

It creates a new object containing everything from the input prop `:value`, but all keys in `qFields` are added to the output, overriding any keys already present.

Finally, this emits the `:value` but with a removed property:

```
this.$emit('input', omit(this.value, key))
```

I am obviously just guessing, impossible to say without knowing what `qFields`, `omit()`, or `key` is, and how the component is used. Let me know how close I am, and more importantly, add more information if this does not help.

Comment: `v-model` seems to still be a thing in Vue(tify) 3 - so what's the difference between `v-model` and `modelValue` in Vue(tify) 3?

Comment: does look like you were right about the needed changes!

Comment: Nice! Happy to hear it. Yes, `v-model` is a core construct in Vue, it is not going away. As to the changes between v2 and v3, have a look at the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html), it explains it better than I could.